# How can I find that dilemma of turtle module of int?

Tags: python

```
import turtle as turtle_module
import random

turtle_module.colormode(255)

tim = turtle_module.Turtle

color_list = [(253, 251, 242), (244, 254, 247), (253, 247, 253), (245, 248, 254),
              (30, 8, 223), (57, 7, 56), (241, 137, 41), (249, 248, 41), (243, 126, 5),
              (5, 247, 6), (30, 242, 33), (234, 7, 2), (191, 6, 96), (56, 13, 251), (226, 43, 69),
              (111, 241, 112), (153, 61, 84), (109, 78, 219), (186, 146, 177), (237, 43, 35),
              (215, 39, 22), (208, 7, 110), (251, 251, 0), (171, 165, 249), (224, 165, 208),
              (145, 135, 228), (248, 162, 153), (253, 9, 5), (84, 57, 185), (2, 3, 118)]


tim.dot(20, random.choice(color_list))


screen = turtle_module.Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

***tim.dot(20,) #it refuses the number of 20***

Comment: Just checking if the answer below solved the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You are not properly creating an instance of `Turtle`:

Change

```
tim = turtle_module.Turtle
```

to

```
tim = turtle_module.Turtle()
```